# Delphi, Winhttp, Google Login, Fusion Tables

Tags: delphi, private, google-fusion-tables, winhttp

This is the continue of my previous question:

[Delphi, WebBrowser, Google Login, FusionTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943626/delphi-webbrowser-google-login-fusiontable)

But the test with WinHTTP also failed as TWebBrowser based test...

And this is one question as you wish... :-)

I have one table what is NOW PUBLIC, but when we will buy non-free account it will be changed to private kind.

I created a simple WinHTTP test, but this also failed.

I can login, I got the "Auth" tag, but the next "private" request returns 401 error.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    WinHttpReq, temp : variant;
    URL, s : String;
    params : TStringList;
    authtoken, query, posts : string;
begin
    URL := 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';

    WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');

    params := TStringList.Create;
    try
        params.Values['accountType'] := 'GOOGLE';
        params.Values['Email'] := csEmail;
        params.Values['Passwd'] := csPwd;
        params.Values['service'] := 'fusiontables';
        params.Values['source'] := csSource;
        posts := EncodeParamsToURL(params);
    finally
        params.Free;
    end;

    URL := URL + '?' + posts;

    WinHttpReq.Open('POST', URL, false);
    WinHttpReq.Send();
    s := WinHttpReq.ResponseText;

    Memo1.Lines.Text := s;

    params := TStringList.Create;
    try
        params.Text := s;
        authtoken := params.Values['Auth'];
        Edit1.Text := authtoken;
    finally
        params.Free;
    end;

    //query := URLEncode('SHOW TABLES');
    query := URLEncode('select * from 1236965');

    url := 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=' + query;

    WinHttpReq.Open('POST', URL, false);
    WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth="' + authToken + '"');
    WinHttpReq.Send();
    s := WinHttpReq.ResponseText;

    Memo1.Lines.Text := s;

end;
```

When I made "select", I got the rows.
But when I want to see the tablenames, I get 401 error...

I'm not sure what cause this error.

a. The free account don't have enough rights to access it privately
b. I set the header wrong
c. I set the csSource wrong (I set it "MyCompanyName-Test-1.0")
d. Other thing I don't know what...

Can anybody help me how to login and access the data successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to GET:

```
WinHttpReq.Open('GET', URL, false);
```

And remove the **"** around your auth token:

```
WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + authToken);
```

The first change is to comply with the [documentation](https://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference.html#ShowTables) (although POST also works). The second change fixes the error.